# Is there a reason why .NET isn't supported in native Visual Studio C++?

Tags: .net, visual-c++

It might look like a stupid question, but I recently realized that .NET implementation is done in C++/C, so I was wondering if there is any technical reason why we can't use .NET libraries in native C++.

Comment: One obvious reason is that there was no equivalent concept of CLR types in C++. Though C++11 is out, no sure if it natively supports the types right now.

Comment: Some parts are written in C++, others are written in C#. Most of the parts written in C++ aren't exposed to .NET code either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The .NET **CLR** is implemented in native code, but using a .NET *library* involves bringing up a CLR in which to execute the code - and interoperating with that library via calls to the CLR.

You *can* use .NET libraries from native C++, but it involves marshalling all the calls via the CLR, just as using native libraries from .NET code does.

Comment: good answer, can you just explain if implementation code for example .Net regex is written in C/C++ or C# and then JITed. My understanding was that it was written in C/C++ and that is the reason for my question.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: I believe *most* of the .NET libraries are written in C# - I don't happen to know the details for regular expressions. That may well go down to native code under the hood.

Answer (score -1):

.net is not *really* native code, it is compiled to byte-code (aka managed code), comparable to how java works. There are however ways to tie native and managed code together, using separate DLL's and with heavy use of data marshaling, but I don't think it is possible to combine them in the same binary.